# Setting pointer using parse server SDK

Tags: javascript, pointers, object, parse-platform, parse-server

I need to create a new element and update it from "current offer" and the old offer as "previews offer". This is what I have:

```
  this.saveCounterOffer = function(currentOffer, price) {
  price = parseInt(price, 10);

  var offers = Parse.Object.extend("Offer");
  var exchanges = Parse.Object.extend("Exchange");

  var offer = new offers(); 
  var offerQuery = new Parse.Query(offers);
  var exchangesQuery = new Parse.Query(exchanges);

  var newOffer = Object.assign(offer, currentOffer);
  delete newOffer.id;
  newOffer.set("price", price); 
  newOffer.save().then(function(response) {
      exchangesQuery.find({
        success: function(exchange) {
          exchange.forEach(function(ex) {
            if(ex.get("currentOffer").id == currentOffer.id) {
              //everything works fine until here
              ex.set("currentOffer", newOffer);
              ex.set("previousOffer", currentOffer);
              console.log('Ex:', ex);
              ex.save().then(function(response) {
                console.log('response', response);
              });
            }
          });
        }, error: function(err) {
          console.log("error", err);
        }
      });
  });
```

I does create a new offer in the offers table, but I get the following error for changing the status in the Exchange table:

```
  {"code":111,"error":"schema mismatch for Exchange.previousOffer; 
  expected Pointer<Offer> but got Object"}
```

I understand it's expecting a pointer but I don't know how to set a pointer. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

So, the parse-server automatically converts a `Parse.Object` to a pointer when it is `set()` into another `Parse.Object`. But in your case, looks like `currentOffer` is not a `Parse.Object`, hence the error.

You can create a `Pointer<Parse.Object>` if you have the `id` of that object, which, looks like you have, since you are using `currentOffer.id`. You just need to use `Parse.Object#createWithoutData()`.

The modified code will look something like this :

```
...
if(ex.get("currentOffer").id == currentOffer.id) {
    ex.set("currentOffer", newOffer);
    // create new pointer and set it
    var pointerToCurrentOffer = offer.createWithoutData(currentOffer.id);
    ex.set("previousOffer", pointerToCurrentOffer);
    console.log('Ex:', ex);
...
```

**EDIT :**

or even better, something like this:

```
...
if(ex.get("currentOffer").id == currentOffer.id) {
    ex.set("previousOffer", ex.get("currentOffer"));
    ex.set("currentOffer", newOffer);
    console.log('Ex:', ex);
...
```

**EDIT 2.0** :

Also, when using `Promise` its always a good idea to get the errors, otherwise they are completely lost. For example this part of your code :

```
...
ex.save().then(function(response) {
    console.log('response', response);
});
...
```

If any error occurs in the above code, it will be lost. You can do this to get the error :

```
...
ex.save().then(function(response) {
    console.log('response', response);
}, function (error) {
    console.error('error', error);
});
...
```

For more info you can check the [documentation](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_createWithoutData).

Comment: I doesn't really work. 

- `previousOffer` gets `currentOffer` data (great!), but it doesn't get saved on the database;
- `currentOffer` gets the newOffer structure and now I don't think it's right. it gets the exchange collection structure. Any ideias of why it's happening?

Comment: I didnt really understand what you are trying to say. Maybe you could edit the question with newer details ? and pinpoint exactly what the problem is ?

Comment: btw why is that the `currentOffer` field of `ex` gettting `newOffer` structure is not correct ? isnt that what you want ?